# Usigng alphabet N'ko charactare in flutter mobile app

Tags: flutter, custom-keyboard

I am currently working on a mobile flutter project and I would like to integrate a keyboard whose characters are the letters of the N'Ko alphabet (Or a way to customize the keys of a keyboard), so I will be very pleased with your help to complete this project.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is too specific, so to solve this issue, you need to create an In-App keyboard with N'Ko characters.

See this link to know more about it.

https://medium.com/flutter-community/custom-in-app-keyboard-in-flutter-b925d56c8465

Create the In-app keyboard and when the user taps on the text field, your in-app keyboard should popup instead of the device keyboard. Set `readOnly` property to true.

```
TextField(
  ...
  showCursor: true,
  readOnly: true,
),
```